# Get the min and max-value of a period by group

Tags: r, dplyr, lubridate

I've got some times per group where participants drink some water (1=youngsters, 2= adults). Unfortunately, I couldn't figure out a nice way to get the difference between min(time) and the max(time). For youngsters it's 21 hours and for adults 6 hours. This apparently does not work:

```
age <-c(1,1,2,1,2) 
time <-hm("22:00","01:00","12:00","16:00","18:00")
drink <- data.frame(age, time)
diff <- drink %>% group_by(age) %>% summarise(max()-min())
```

Comment: What do you mean by `time`? Is time when when participant drank water OR is it time taken to drink water?

Comment: First of all, this should be probably `time <- hm("22:00","01:00","12:00","16:00","18:00") ; 
food <- data.frame(sex, time)`. (you need to put the times into quotes, otherwise you are running `\`:\`` on the numbers and you need to define `food` too), second of all, you should probably do `summarise(max(time)-min(time))` (e.g., you need to insert some values into `min`/`max`).

Comment: Also, it seems like `min`/`max` doesn't know how to handle this class, you''ll probably need to extract the hour yourself while defining `time`, e.g. `time <- hm("22:00","01:00","12:00","16:00","18:00")@hour`

Comment: Furthermore, you might find it easier to display the results if you named the summary, such as `summarise(rng=max(time)-min(time))`, otherwise the column name will the expression itself (not often desired).

Comment: May be OP should use `time_length` to calculate difference between `min` and `max`. i.e. `food %>% group_by(sex) %>% summarise(gap = (max(time_length(time))-min(time_length(time))))`

Comment: Sorry guys - I cleaned up my code. Now it should be clearer.
@MKR: The time when they drank water

Comment: @MKR: A get a tibble with 2 identical values of 75600. However, I wanted to get for 1: 19 hours and for 2: 6 hours.

Comment: @RobinRosine Try this: `food %>% mutate(tl = time_length(time)) %>% 
  group_by(sex) %>% summarise(gap = max(tl) - min(tl))`

Comment: @MKR Very nice work!!!! Thank you very much! And with: a <- drink 
seconds_to_period(a$gap) I can convert it in hours!

Answer (score 1):

One solution can be achieved using `time_length` function from `lubridate`.

```
library(lubridate)

#data
sex <-c(1,1,2,1,2) 
time <-hm(c("22:00","01:00","12:00","16:00","18:00"))
food <- data.frame(sex, time)


food %>% mutate(tl_sec = time_length(time)) %>% 
  group_by(sex) %>% summarise(diff_secs = max(tl_sec) - min(tl_sec)) %>%
  as.data.frame()

#    sex diff_secs
# 1   1     75600
# 2   2     21600


#Diff in HRS
food %>% mutate(tl_sec = time_length(time)) %>% 
  group_by(sex) %>% summarise(diff_hrs = (max(tl_sec) - min(tl_sec))/3600) %>%
  as.data.frame()

#     sex diff_hrs
# 1   1       21
# 2   2        6
```

Comment: If there are some NA in the time variable, should I work with na.rm=TRUE? Or is there a better way?

Comment: @RobinRosine Obviously you have to use `na.rm = TRUE`.